# Coordinates of Canadian provinces to build Google Maps polygons?

Tags: javascript, maps, polygon

I need to have clickable states/provinces on my Google Map. I have achieved that for USA using this file:

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/states.js

Does anyone have anything similar for Canada, so I can avoid gathering all this info from the map manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the data from the KML file - here is one

http://geocommons.com/overlays/135261.kml

or you can search geocommons for a data set